# GAE Flex Golang Development Env

Tags: google-app-engine, go, localhost, google-cloud-platform

I used to develop the application with GAE Standard using Golang and now I moved to the new GAE Flex with Golang. I have some confused issues and problem mainly in development environment as follows:

1. Running the application in local server
   GAE Standard (Using go_appengine APIs)

`~/go_appengine/goapp serve .`

GAE Flex (based on the official document, using Golang standard runtime)

`go run *.go`

In case of GAE standard, everything is build and run under proprietary APIs which works fine. Anyway, in GAE Flex, I struck on the runtime problem where I need to stop server and start `go run *.go` everytime I changed the code.

**How to run Golang server locally without manually restart server everytime when the code has changed?**

2. Setting up static_dir in app.yaml
   GAE Standard (Using go_appengine APIs)

`handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: houston/_template/_static`

It works fine.

GAE Flex

`handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: houston/_template/_static`

It does not work (regarding no APIs like GAE Standard)

**How Golang serves static_files and static_dir for GAE Flex?**

Comment: You should ask these questions as 2 separate posts, eventually referencing each-other for context - keeps things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some of solution. With [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) you can solve this tasks. Indeed, when a go file is modified, a task compile the application in the 'bin' folder then another launch the executable.

https://medium.com/@etiennerouzeaud/autoreload-your-go-webserver-with-gulp-ee5e231d133d